# independent sample t-test in R using test statistics (mean, std. dev, count)

Tags: r, r-package, t-test

Hi I am trying to do an independent sample t-test, but do not have full data, only summary statistics. Is there an R package where I can use the mean, standard deviation, and count for each sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [TTestA function from the DescTools package](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/DescTools/html/TTestA.html).

Also: you can implement this yourself! From the Wikipedia article on t tests, [section on independent sample t test, unequal sample size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Equal_or_unequal_sample_sizes,_similar_variances_(_%7F%27%22%60UNIQ--postMath-00000011-QINU%60%22%27%7F_%3C_%7F%27%22%60UNIQ--postMath-00000012-QINU%60%22%27%7F_%3C_2))

Example data:

```
means <- c(2.5, 3.7)
stddev <- c(1.5, 1.8)
n <- c(25,35)
```

Calculate summary statistics:

```
df <- sum(n)-2
stddev_pooled <- sqrt(sum((n-1)*stddev^2)/df)
tstat <- (means[1]-means[2])/(stddev_pooled*sqrt(sum(1/n)))
```

Now calculate the p-value:

```
2*pt(abs(tstat),df=df,lower.tail=FALSE)
```

If you want the unequal variances case you can implement the formula in the next section of the Wikipedia page (Welch's t-test).